# Run apps script for only one form

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

I have a workbook with two sheets in it. The first sheet gets populated from Form 1, the second sheet gets populated from form 2. I have the below script but only want it to run when form 1 gets filled out. In it's current form it doesn't even run. Any help would be appreciated.

```
function setTrigger() {
  var form = FormApp.openByID('123456789abcdefg');
  ScriptApp.newTrigger('formSubmit').forForm(form).onFormSubmit().create();
}

function formSubmit(e) {
  var r = e.range;
  var row = r.getRow();
  var min = 1;
  var max = 1000000;
  var selectId = makeArray(min, max);
  if (row > 2) {
    var currentId = r.offset(2 - row, 5, row - 2, 1).getValues();
    for (var i = 0; i < currentId.length; i++) {
      selectId.splice(selectId.indexOf(currentId[i][0]), 1);
      if (selectId.length == 0) selectId = makeArray(min, max);
    }
  }
  r.offset(0, 5, 1, 1).setValue(selectId[Math.floor(Math.random() * selectId.length)]);
}

function makeArray(min, max) {
  var output = [];
  for (var i = min; i <= max; i++) {
    output.push(i);
  }
  return output;
}
```

Comment: What's the error that you are getting? Does the trigger not run or does the script setting the trigger not run?

Answer (score 0):

Use e.range.getSheet() to check the if the submitted response correspond to the first or the second sheets.